# Custom validation in react-bootstrap forms not working

Tags: css, reactjs, forms, react-bootstrap, required

I'm trying to add custom validation logic to my `react-bootstrap` forms, but `isInvalid` doesn't seem to be respected. As soon as `validated={true}` is set on the form, it always validates non-empty strings, regardless of `isValid` or `isInvalid`. The invalid message is displayed, but the field shows as green. See here:

[image]

Here is the offending code:

```js
 <Form noValidate validated={formValidated} id="bidForm">
    <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicBidding">
       <Form.Label>Bid Amount</Form.Label>
       <InputGroup hasValidation className="mb-3">
           <InputGroup.Text id="inputGroupPrepend">$</InputGroup.Text>
           <Form.Control
              required
              value={bidAmount}
              isInvalid={!(parseInt(bidAmount) > 0) && formValidated}
              onChange={e => setBidAmount(e.target.value)}
           />
           <InputGroup.Text id="inputGroupAppend">.00</InputGroup.Text>
           <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
               Please select a dollar amount {`>`} 0
           </Form.Control.Feedback>
        </InputGroup>
    </Form.Group>
    <...>
</Form>
```

I was able to get it to work using a `pattern=` regex on the input, but I'm planning to do more complex validation where a regex won't be sufficient. How can I get `react-bootstrap` to follow `isValid` and `isInvalid` properly? Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The docs don't do a *great* job of making this clear, but the form-level `validated` attribute hooks directly into HTML5's native validation library and can't be used simultaneously with other validation techniques. So if you're using the native option and an input doesn't violate any of the *native* validation options ([`required`, `pattern`, etc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation#using_built-in_form_validation)), then the input will be considered valid. Since you don't have any of the native validation attributes besides `required` on your bid input, "foo" is valid as far as React-Bootstrap is concerned.

(If you're thinking 'well that's bad code design to let you use both simultaneously', I'd tend to agree with you.)

You'll note that with your current code, if you enter "foo" and submit the form the element actually *does* have an `is-invalid` class applied to it, but it's also got the `:valid` psuedo-selector applied to it because the entire form was validated, which seems to take precedence from a CSS perspective:

[image]

The best solution here is to use *either* the native HTML5 validation option ([detailed here](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/forms/validation/#native-html5-form-validation)) *or* [roll your own](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/forms/validation/#form-libraries-and-server-rendered-styles) (with or without a helper library like Formik), *but not both simultaneously*.

If you're trying to avoid validating until the input is actually in a "dirty" state (e.g. the user filled it out or submitted the form), you can do something like this ([CodePen here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-playground-forked-8mbxqz?file=/src/App.js:1046-1294)):

```
        <Form.Control
          required
          value={bidAmount}
          isInvalid={!(parseInt(bidAmount) > 0) && (bidAmount.length || formSubmitted)}
          onChange={(e) => setBidAmount(e.target.value)}
        />
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! The screenshot that showed both `:valid` and `:invalid` was helpful. I ended up migrating over to use Formik, and it's much easier to customize the validation now.

Comment: This is a great answer but I think there is one additional point here. You should use both use `isValid` and `isInvalid` properties together, and while a bit counter intuitive I found that if you dont specify the `isValid` property then it won't show the valid state (green border and tick) unless the Form `validated` proeprty is also true.